# Query in ManyToMany Relation Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is driving me crazy.

I have a normal Symfony2 Security System, with User and Role entities with a ManyToMany relation between them.

Lets suppose that i have 3 roles in the database, `ROLE_1`, `ROLE_2` and `ROLE_3`.

How can i retrieve all Users that dont have `ROLE_3` for example ?

I already tried something like:

```
$qb->innerJoin('u.roles', 'r , 'WITH', $qb->expr()->notIn('r.id', ':roles')))
                ->setParameter('roles', array(3));
```

My Question is, how can i Query in the JoinTable ?

Comment: Try this DQL: `SELECT u FROM MyBundle:User u JOIN u.roles r WHERE r NOT IN (:roles)`

Comment: Keeps returning An User with ROLE_3. The thing is: User1(ROLE_1, ROLE_3) User2(ROLE_1) User3(ROLE_1). I want to get Users without ROLE_3 so in this case only User2 and User3 should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a SQL question than it is a Symfony or Doctrine question. The first solution that comes to mind is a subquery, although that may or may not be the most efficient way to handle this problem. Something like this:

```
SELECT username
FROM users
WHERE users.id NOT IN (
    SELECT users.id
    FROM users
    INNER JOIN user_roles
    ON users.id = user_roles.user_id
    INNER JOIN roles
    ON user_roles.role_id = roles.id
    WHERE roles.id NOT IN (1,2)
);
```

Where 1 and 2 are the IDs of the role you want to include in your results, and `user_roles` is the bridge table between users and roles.